# background-color attribute of table row (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, attributes

I have a html table and press a key in a table cell. Now I want to check if any of the following table rows has the background color #FFFFCC. I tried this with the jQuery-code

```
var t = $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('[background="#FFFFCC"]').eq(0);
   if (t.length > 0)
   //
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use an attribute-equals selector, which won't work since `background` isn't an attribute. What you need to do, I think, is:

```
var t = $(this).closest('tr').nextAll().filter(function(){
            if ($(this).css('background-color') == '#ffffcc'){
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ok, just added a class to the tr´s and used the class, that worked. Thanks anyway.